# MVC kendogrid not showing datetime string value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid that returns all the results except for the first column, being the date. It is showing as blank. In my viewmodel the reviewdate is of type string. In my controller I have the reviewdate converted to a string. I know that reviewdate returns MM/dd/yyyy from debug.

Controller snippet:

```
foreach (var item in query)
{
    model.Add(new PreviousReviewViewModel()
    {
        ReviewId = item.ReviewId,
        ReviewDate = item.NextReviewDt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"),
        Rating = item.Rating,
        SubmittedFl = item.SubmittedFl
    });

}
```

In my view i have the grid as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<PreviousReviewViewModel>()
      .Name("Grid")
      //.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:450px;" })
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Template(
            @<text>
                @Html.ActionLink(Model.ReviewDate, "SavedFormsIndex", new { Controller = "Forms", id = Model.ReviewId })
            </text>).ClientTemplate(@"<a href=""/Forms/SavedFormsIndex?id=#=ReviewId#""></a>").Title("Review Date");
          columns.Bound(m => m.Rating).Title("Composite Rating"); //rating is the avg
          columns.Bound(m => m.SubmittedFl).Title("Submitted");
      })
      .Pageable(p => p.Numeric(false).PreviousNext(false).Refresh(true))
      .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
      .Scrollable()
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .PageSize(2147483647)
          .Read(read => read.Action("read_PrevProjReviews", "Forms", new { id = ViewBag.ProjectId })) 
      )
```

Comment: [Refer here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/template-columns-not-displaying-data) and the link on that page - note there is no text between the `<a></a>` tags

Comment: ah.. thank you. works perfectly by entering ReviewDate between the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try change your client template

```
.ClientTemplate(@"<a href=""/Forms/SavedFormsIndex?id=#=ReviewId#"">#=ReviewDate#</a>
```